# How to send properly files in a client-server application?

Tags: c, windows, client, send

I want to make a client-server application when a client can register, login, broadcast a message to another clients, send files and so on. Everything, except sending files works pretty well.

In the client application I made a separate thread for every file that I want to send. Reading the file is successful, but sending is not that good. I should make a thread in server project for receiving the bytes sent by the client?

I want sending files to be asynchronous, so that another clients can communicate with server when server is receiving a file.
The thread for reading file and sending data to server:

```
DWORD WINAPI SendFile(LPVOID param)
{
    FileStruct* fileStruct = (FileStruct*)param;
    CM_DATA_BUFFER* dataToSend = NULL;
    CM_SIZE dataToSendSize = MAXLENGTH;
    CM_ERROR error;
    CM_SIZE sendBytesCount = 0;
    FILE* f = fopen(fileStruct->filePath, "rb");
    char buffer[2];
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        perror((const char*)f);
    }
    char messageBuffer[10];
    while (fread(buffer, 1, 1, f) == 1)
    {
        *(int*)messageBuffer = SENDTYPE;
        messageBuffer[4] = buffer[0];
        messageBuffer[5] = 0;

        dataToSend = NULL;
        error = CreateDataBuffer(&dataToSend, dataToSendSize);
        if (CM_IS_ERROR(error))
        {
            _tprintf_s(TEXT("Failed to create SEND data buffer with err-code=0x%X!\n"), error);
            DestroyClient(fileStruct->client);
            UninitCommunicationModule();
            return (DWORD)-1;
        }

        error = CopyDataIntoBuffer(dataToSend, (const CM_BYTE*)messageBuffer, (CM_SIZE)strlen(messageBuffer));
        if (CM_IS_ERROR(error))
        {
            _tprintf_s(TEXT("CopyDataIntoBuffer failed with err-code=0x%X!\n"), error);
            DestroyDataBuffer(dataToSend);
            DestroyClient(fileStruct->client);
            UninitCommunicationModule();
            return (DWORD)-1;
        }
        error = SendDataToServer(fileStruct->client, dataToSend, &sendBytesCount);
        if (CM_IS_ERROR(error))
        {
            _tprintf_s(TEXT("SendDataToServer failed with err-code=0x%X!\n"), error);
            DestroyDataBuffer(dataToSend);
            DestroyClient(fileStruct->client);
            UninitCommunicationModule();
            return (DWORD)-1;
        }
        DestroyDataBuffer(dataToSend);
    }
    return (DWORD)0;

}
```

Here is a part of code from Thread Server responsible for receiving data :

```
while ((error = ReceiveDataFromClient(newClient, receivedData, &numberOfBytesRead)) == 0)
    {
        message = (char*)receivedData->DataBuffer;
        if (CM_IS_ERROR(error))
        {
            _tprintf_s(TEXT("ReceiveDataFormServer failed with err-code=0x%X!\n"), error);
            DestroyDataBuffer(sendData);
            DestroyDataBuffer(receivedData);
            break;
        }
        type = *(int*)receivedData->DataBuffer;
        printf("%x\n", type);
        if (type == SENDTYPE)
        {
            printf("%c", (char)receivedData->DataBuffer[4]);
            DestroyDataBuffer(receivedData);
            receivedData = NULL;
            error = CreateDataBuffer(&receivedData, MAXLENGTH);
            if (CM_IS_ERROR(error))
            {
                _tprintf_s(TEXT("Creating receivedDataBuffer failed with err-code =0x%X!\n"), error);
                UninitCommunicationModule();
            }
            continue;
        }
```

This is ReceiveDataFromClient function:

```
CM_ERROR ReceiveDataFromClient(CM_SERVER_CLIENT* Client, CM_DATA_BUFFER* DataBufferToReceive, CM_SIZE* SuccessfullyReceivedBytesCount)
{
    if (Client == NULL || DataBufferToReceive == NULL || SuccessfullyReceivedBytesCount == NULL)
        return CM_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    CM_ERROR error = ReceiveData(
        Client->ClientConnection
        , DataBufferToReceive->DataBuffer
        , DataBufferToReceive->DataBufferSize
        , SuccessfullyReceivedBytesCount
    );
    if (CM_IS_ERROR(error))
        return error;

    DataBufferToReceive->UsedBufferSize = *SuccessfullyReceivedBytesCount;

    return error;
}
```

And this is ReceiveData function:

```
CM_ERROR ReceiveData(CM_CONNECTION* Connection, CM_BYTE* OutputDataBuffer, CM_SIZE OutputDataBufferSize, CM_SIZE* SuccessfullyReceivedBytesCount)
{
    if (Connection == NULL)
        return CM_INVALID_CONNECTION;

    if (INVALID_SOCKET == Connection->ConnectionSocket)
        return CM_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    int receiveResult = recv(Connection->ConnectionSocket, (char*) OutputDataBuffer, OutputDataBufferSize, 0);
    if (receiveResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        CM_LOG_ERROR(TEXT("recv failed with err-code=0x%X!"), WSAGetLastError());
        return CM_CONNECTION_RECEIVE_FAILED;
    }

    if (receiveResult == 0)
        return CM_CONNECTION_TERMINATED;

    *SuccessfullyReceivedBytesCount = (CM_SIZE)receiveResult;

    return CM_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If you made the client do multithreading, what keeps you from making the server do the same? Please be more specific about what you tried and were you fail.

Comment: Client does multithreading: i have one thread for writing commands like echo, login, register and one thread per every file i want to send. The server has one thread per every client connected, in this way i can reponse to every client asynchronous. I don't know how to send files, without being corrupted. I use recv() for every client, even if the client wants to send a command, or a byte from a file. The commands works, but the files received by server are corrupted. Suppose we know that the client sends bytes correctly through socket, server received the file incorrectly.

Comment: So then the question is more: "How to send files reliable over the network?", right? And is not related to any multithreading issues ...

Comment: I recommend to 1st code a single threaded client-server pair, which reliable transfers a really huge file (>100MB) over the open network, not just only inside your dev box or local LAN. This is not a trivial task. Having completed this task successfully you learned where the possible pitfalls are.

Comment: I've found something about my code. If i call printf for the message before sending to server, the file will be less corrupted.

Comment: This looks like  timing issue, so it's more or less a coincident. Dare to show the sending and even more important the receiving code? Else this all just guessing, an the question will most likely be closed soon.

Comment: "*I use recv() for every client*": I do not see any calls to `recv()`.

Comment: The code is no taking into account the value ending up in `numberOfBytesRead`. Assuming TCP its value can be as small as `1`, completely independent on how many bytes have been sent. One call to `send()` N bytes can in the worth case end up in N calls to `recv()` each receiving exactly only 1 byte.